# password solver loop count in python

Tags: python, loops, count, passwords, iteration

I'm writing a program in python that allows you to enter a password, then python iterates through all of the ascii characters to try to guess your password. I have got it working but i am trying to build into it a count of run through's see how many attempts the computer took to guess the character. I'm just not sure if the runthru's is counting the correct number of iterations? Any advice welcome.

Code is below.....

```
password=input("Enter a password:")
print("Your password is: ",password)
print("Your password length is: ",len(password))
length=len(password)
crackedlistx=[]
runthrus=0
lengthx=len(crackedlistx)
passwordlist=password.split()
print("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
while length>len(crackedlistx):
    for i in range(0,length):
        for c in (chr(i) for i in range(0,128)):
            runthrus=runthrus+1
            if password[i]==c:
                crackedlistx.append(c)
                runthrus=runthrus+1
                print("Finding",len(crackedlistx),"of",length,"characters.")
                print("Your password being solved:",crackedlistx)
                print("Percentage complete: ",100*(len(crackedlistx)/length),"%")
print("Your final password solved:",''.join(crackedlistx))
print("Run through's taken:",runthrus)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the second `runthrus` increment:

```
...
runthrus=runthrus+1
if password[i]==c:
    crackedlistx.append(c)
    runthrus=runthrus+1  # delete this line
    print("Finding",len(crackedlistx),"of",length,"characters.")
    ...
```

Also, you can replace `runthrus=runthrus+1` with `runthrus += 1`